# Remove the String value using Java

Tags: java, string-matching

I need to remove the String value like cat and fish from the String variable.
I done some sample Java code to remove string values.

```
public static void deleteAccNode(String refId){
    String refId [] = {"Fish","Dog","Dolphins","rowboat","Fish","sailor","Cat","cats","Cat","Fish",
        "Fish","Tree","Fishes","Cat","Cat","CAT","Cat"};

        try {
            System.out.println("GeneralLength"+refId.length);
            for (int n = refId.length; n <= 1; ){
            if(refId.equals("Cat")){
               System.out.println("cat : :"+refId);
                How to remove the String value?remove("Cat");
                }else if(refId.equals("Fish")){
                    System.out.println("Fish : :"+refId);
                    How to remove the String value?remove("Fish");
                }
            n--;
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Required output: Dog,Dolphins,rowboat,sailor,cats, Tree, Fishes,CAT
But, Current output: NullPointerException

Comment: so ... what is stopping you?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: `String = "Fish","Dog","Dolphins","rowboat","Fish","sailor","Cat","cats","Cat","Fish",
    +"Fish","Tree","Fishes","Cat","Cat","CAT","Cat";` Never seen something like this before. I don't think it compiles?

Comment: @ifly6 nope, it won't.

Answer (score 1):

This is just one way, there is a lot more, you could have just googled this.

```
  String[] stringArray = { "Cat", "Fish", "CatFish", "Elephant" };
  final List<String> newArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
  for ( final String string : stringArray )
  {
    if ( !(string.equals( "Cat" ) || string.equals( "Fish" )) )
    {
      newArrayList.add( string );
    }
  }

  stringArray = (String[]) newArrayList.toArray();
```